# Which are the four equivalence classes to the relation R on the integers Z defined by xRy ⇔ x 2 ≡ y 2 (mod 7)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

This is the second part of a question that I don't get.
First part was for proving it is an equivalent relation, which I did, but I have a hard time finding out it's equivalence classes. How should I go about finding them?

A method, or thought process would be highly appreciated because I want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle there could be only up to $7$ equivalence classes, since the group of integers mod $7$ has only seven equivalence classes.

We then can ask ourselves, which numbers (mod $7$), when squared, yield which of the seven potential squares.  Well,
$$
0^2 \equiv 0\\1^2\equiv 1\\ 2^2 \equiv 4 \\3^2 \equiv 2 
$$
and for the other three values,
$$
(7-k)^2 \equiv (-k)^2 \equiv k^2
$$
So the four equivalence classes are 
$$
\{0\}, \{1,6\}, \{2,5\}, \{3,4\}
$$

Comment: Btw is 3^2≡2 correct? It doesn't make sense. But I am a newbie.